# Unable to import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spark-cassandra-connector

I have the spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.0.0-M3.jar in my path but still unable to  import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext.  Is this in some other package- all documentation points to this package (or deprecated).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `CassandraSQLContext` has been deprecated. Please check https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-399. Please check SO post [how to use Cassandra Context in spark 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423131/how-to-use-cassandra-context-in-spark-2-0) for the details.